# How to make first array value to uppercase

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make first array value to uppercase.

Code:

```
$data = $this->positions_model->array_from_post(array('position', 'label'));
$this->positions_model->save($data, $id);
```

So before `save($data, $id)` to database I want to convert `position` value to uppercase. I have tried by this

```
$data['position'] = strtoupper($data['position']);
```

but than it is not storing the value in db with uppercase but as it is what user inputs.

Current output of `$data`:

```
Array ( [position] => it [label] => Information Technology )
```

And I want `it` in uppercase as `IT`

**Added Model Method**

```
public function get_positions_array($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
{

    $this->db->get($this->_table_name);        
    $positions = parent::get($id, $single);

    $array = array();
    foreach($positions as $pos){
    $array[] = get_object_vars($pos);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

**Main MY_Model method**

```
public function array_from_post($fields)
{
    $data = array();

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: can you show your model function

Comment: @Nouphal.M Please have a look my updated question for the same. Thanks

Comment: Just wonder, is it really difficult like impossible?

Comment: that's not your model function...your model function is array_from_post(). Codeskiller's code below is correct (although I have no idea what a "read only" array is in php). If it doesn't work, put a var_dump() before the save() line and see what is happening

Comment: @jmadsen okay I have added that too, please refer the last part of the question

Comment: no you didn't - put a var_dump() in and debug your code. this is a really very simple issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$data = $this->positions_model->array_from_post(array('position', 'label'));
$data['position'] = strtoupper($data['position']);
$this->positions_model->save($data, $id);
```

If Its not, then $data array have only read attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But as I mentioned in my question, it is modifying the value but not storing to the database with strtoupper() but the way use inputs

Answer (score 0):

The `array_from_post()` method returns an array with the format below:

```
$data = array(
  'position' => 'it',
  'label'    => 'Information Technology'
);
```

So, you could make first value of the array to uppercase, by using [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) functions as follows:

```php
$data = array_map(function($a) {
  static $i = 0;
  if ($i === 0) { $i++; return strtoupper($a); }
  else return $a;
}, $array);
```

**Note:** This only works on PHP 5.3+, for previous versions, [use the function name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-4968) instead.

Here is the `array_walk` example, which modifies the `$data`:

```php
array_walk($data, function(&$value, $key) {
    static $i = 0;
    if ($i == 0) { $i++; $value = strtoupper($value); }
});
```

Again, if you're using PHP 5.2.x or lower, you could [pass the function name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#example-5009) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It is giving an error on `if ('position' == array_search($a, $data))` line Error: `Message: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given` any idea?

Comment: @JatinSoni I prefer using `array_walk` myself, and I recommend to. But the `array_map` approach works well for me: http://3v4l.org/TiXNa Make sure you've defined `$data` globally inside the function: `global $data;`.